# java multithreading split calculation between a given number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have simple method that calculates pow of each number in array and returns these numbers in new array ... My question is how I can split this calculation to given number of threads and thereby speed up the execution of the method

```
public class ExtClass{
    public static long pow(long a, int b) {
        if (b == 0)        return 1;
        if (b == 1)        return a;
        if ((b & 1) == 0)  return     pow (a * a, b/2);
        else               return a * pow(a * a, b/2);

    }

    public static long[] val(long[] a, int p) {
        long[] result_array = new long[a.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            result_array[i] = pow(a[i], p);
        }

        return result_array;
    }
```

P.S.  I'm totally noob in java and need your help plz =)

Comment: I don't believe that you can guarantee that the threads are run on different cores anyway as that is up to the OS, did you consider this? However making different threads would at least give the OS that option. The point I'm trying to make is that `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` is not necessarily useful. You can make an arbitrary number of threads and this would be ok, also I would not give each thread one result to compute at a time, I would batch them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a high level:

1. You create a callable class, that has the implementation of the,  pow method.
2. You create a executor based on the max available processors that you seemed to have figured out.
3. You create the callables and submit them to the executor.
4. Using the Future's returned you collate the results

These links should get you started:
https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6
http://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example

Comment: Oh yes, you need not limit the thread pool to the max number of available Cores. As there are various other factors that go into how threads will work based on the other waits like IO, network etc.